# Relationship between holonomy and fundamental group

Tags: differential-geometry, gauge-theory, group-theory, topology, wilson-loop

In my notes of topological QFT we demonstrated that the holonomy associated with a path in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is invariant under smooth deformation of the path if the connection is flat.

Then I wrote:

> If we do a smooth deformation of the path shrinking it to a point, since the holonomy $H_{\gamma}$ is invariant it corresponds to the trivial element of a group: then the set of the holonomies $H_{\gamma}(A)$ associated with a loop $\gamma$ gives a representation of the fundamental group $\pi_1(M)$ in the structure group $G$ [...] for a global transformation under coniugation (since holonomy transforms with coniugation under gauge transformation e.d.)

1. Why "since the holonomy $H_{\gamma}$ is invariant it corresponds to the trivial element of a group"?
2. What does it means that "the set of the holonomies $H_{\gamma}(A)$ associated with a loop $\gamma$ gives a representation of the fundamental group $\pi_1(M)$"? If I do have curvature the holonomy is not invariant anymore under smooth deformation, yet if the manifold has trivial $\pi_1(M)$ the path could be still shrinked to a point: are the set of holonomies still a representation of the unique trivial element of $\pi_1(M)$?
3. What information gives us the fact that the holonomy transforms with coniugation under gauge transformation? Is it just useful to construct the Wilson loop as gauge invariant, or does it have a geometrical meaning related to the flatness of the connection? Why does he say a "global" transformation, since the gauge transformation is local?